# ArcObjects 10.1 Error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, file-geodatabase

I am trying to execute the below sample code [Copying or loading data while preserving GlobalID values](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Copying_or_loading_data_while_preserving_GlobalID_values/00010000019v000000/) from ArcObjects 10.1 help. I am creating IWorkspace from FileGDB-Path using `workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile` and passing to this function.

```
// Converts a GlobalID field to a GUID field.
public static void ConvertGlobalIdToGuid(IWorkspace workspace, String datasetName)
{
    // Open the table.
    IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = (IFeatureWorkspace)workspace;
    ITable table = featureWorkspace.OpenTable(datasetName);

    // Get the GlobalID field.
    IClassEx classEx = (IClassEx)table;
    if (!classEx.HasGlobalID)
    {
        throw new Exception(String.Format("No GlobalID column in table: {0}.",
            datasetName));
    }
    String globalIDFieldName = classEx.GlobalIDFieldName;

    // Convert the GlobalID column to a GUID column.
    IClassSchemaEditEx classSchemaEditEx = (IClassSchemaEditEx)table;
    classSchemaEditEx.UnregisterGlobalIDColumn(globalIDFieldName);
}
```

But unfortunately, i am getting exception on the line

```
IClassSchemaEditEx classSchemaEditEx = (IClassSchemaEditEx)table;
```

Exception trace:

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  Message=Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IClassSchemaEditEx'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{F14139C3-B498-4B42-AA6C-5960028554E0}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
  Source=CMSS.Windows.FGDB.Utilities
  StackTrace:
       at CMSS.Windows.FGDB.Utilities.frmUtilities.ConvertGlobalIdToGuid(IWorkspace workspace, String datasetName) in C:\Dev Temp\CMSS.Windows.FGDB.Utilities\CMSS.Windows.FGDB.Utilities\Form1.cs:line 40
       at CMSS.Windows.FGDB.Utilities.frmUtilities.btnConvertGlobalId_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Dev Temp\CMSS.Windows.FGDB.Utilities\CMSS.Windows.FGDB.Utilities\Form1.cs:line 86
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at CMSS.Windows.FGDB.Utilities.Program.Main() in C:\Dev Temp\CMSS.Windows.FGDB.Utilities\CMSS.Windows.FGDB.Utilities\Program.cs:line 22
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

I have tried re-install/new-install the ArcObjects SDK. But the exception still occurs.

It would be helpful, if someone give some idea about this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The help file for this Interface says *"These methods apply to unversioned ArcSDE feature classes and tables only"*. But you say you are accessing a file geodatabase, I guess this is the problem?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Do you know any other to achieve this for file geodatabases?

Comment: Looks like this [guy](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/28831-Need-workaround-for-Global-ID-unregistration-back-to-GUID-temporarily.) was trying the same thing 2 years ago but got no response...

Comment: Finally, I have loaded my File GDB in ArcSDE and achieved this. Thanks.